# How to remove string between two characters every time they occur

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I need to get rid of any text inside `<` and `>`, including the two delimiters themselves.

So for example, from string

`<brev-y>th</brev-y><sw-ex>a</sw-ex><sl>t</sl>​`

I would like to get this one

`that`

This is what i've tried so far:

```
var str = annotation.split(' ');
str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("<") + 1, str.lastIndexOf(">"))
```

But it doesn't work for every `<` and `>`.

I'd rather not use RegEx if possible, but I'm happy to hear if it's the only option.

Comment: Are this always html or xml tags that you want to remove?

Comment: @Nirnae sure, just a second.

Comment: @Ursus Most of the [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/822486/5290909) work with the example you provided.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the [replace method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) with [/<[^>]*>/g](https://regex101.com/r/hB2vI4/1).
It matches `<` followed by `[^>]*` any amount of [non](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)`>` until `>` globally.

```js
var str = '<brev-y>th</brev-y><sw-ex>a</sw-ex><sl>t</sl>';
str = str.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, "");
alert(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

For string removal you can use RegExp, it is ok.

```
"<brev-y>th</brev-y><sw-ex>a</sw-ex><sl>t</sl>​".replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/g, "")
```

Comment: Thanks, but are you sure that regex is correct? It doesn't seem to replace anything...

Comment: Yes, just copy the code-line; press F12 to open console; insert the line; press enter. You should see "that" in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Since the text you want is always after a > character, you could split it at that point, and then the first character in each String of the array would be the character you need. For example:

```
String[] strings = stringName.split("<");
String word = "";
for(int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    word += strings[i].charAt(0);
}
```

This is probably glitchy right now, but I think this would work. You don't need to actually remove the text between the "<>"- just get the character right after a '>'

Comment: tenbits's answer with RegExp is better, but if you reeaaally don't want to use it, this will work...

Comment: @t.niese No, I said tenbits is better than mine. Mine just doesn't use RegExp

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this.  Some are better than others.  I haven't done one lately for these two specific characters, so I took a minute and wrote some code that may work. I will describe how it works. Create a function with a loop that copies an incoming string, character by character, to an outgoing string. Make the function a string type so it will return your modified string. Create the loop to scan from incoming from string[0] and while less than string.length().  Within the loop, add an if statement.  When the if statement sees a "<" character in the incoming string it stops copying, but continues to look at every character in the incoming string until it sees the ">" character. When the ">" is found, it starts copying again. It's that simple.

The following code may need some refinement, but it should get you started on the method described above.  It's not the fastest and not the most elegant but the basic idea is there. This did compile, and it ran correctly, here, with no errors. In my test program it produced the correct output. However, you may need to test it further in the context of your program.

```
  string filter_on_brackets(string str1)
{
    string str2 = "";
    int copy_flag = 1;
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < str1.length();i++)
    {
        if(str1[i] == '<')
        {
            copy_flag = 0;
        }
        if(str1[i] == '>')
        {
            copy_flag = 2;
        }

        if(copy_flag == 1)
        {
            str2 += str1[i];
        }

        if(copy_flag == 2)
        {
            copy_flag = 1;
        }


    }
    return str2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression is not the only option, but it's a pretty good option.

You can easily parse the string to remove the tags, for example by using a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) where the `<` and `>` characters turns on and off a state of ignoring characters. There are other methods of course, some shorter, some more efficient, but they will all be a few lines of code, while a regular expression solution is just a single replace.

Example:

```js
function removeHtml1(str) {
  return str.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '');
}

function removeHtml2(str) {
  var result = '';
  var ignore = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var c = str.charAt(i);
    switch (c) {
      case '<': ignore = true; break;
      case '>': ignore = false; break;
      default: if (!ignore) result += c;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

var s = "<brev-y>th</brev-y><sw-ex>a</sw-ex><sl>t</sl>";

console.log(removeHtml1(s));
console.log(removeHtml2(s));
```